# ¿Por qué debo poner especificadores antes de un dato en C?

Tags: c

Estoy haciendo un algoritmo simple, pero no se por qué tengo que colocar un especificador antes de un dato, en lenguaje C.

me refiero a esto

```
  scanf("%i",&varn1);
```

Comment: ¿Te refieres al tipo de variable? `int, float, double...`?

Comment: ¿Te refieres al `"%i"`?

Comment: Por favor, aclara a qué te refieres con especificador, así podremos intentar resolver tu pregunta.

Comment: si,me refriero al "%i", disculpen por no saber especificar apenas empiezo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) es conocida por ser propensa e errores e insegura.

El motivo por el que tiene esa fama es porque los parámetros de entrada son todos convertidos a un mismo tipo antes de pasarlos a la función y después ser impresos. Al perder la información de los tipos originales (los tipos dentro de la función son todos iguales, pero fuera de la misma pueden ser diferentes) se necesita especificar en la cadena de formato el tipo de dato que quieres imprimir.

Answer (score 0):

Si a lo que refieres a es la "%i" entonces:

Es la mascara: que utilizamos para cuando leemos o guardamos un dato le estamos diciendo al compilador el tipo de archivo que leemos/guardamos. No solo basta con declararlo al inicio sino que hay que respetar dichas mascaras en todo el programa. Ya que este lenguaje es estructurado y "lineal". Si decimos que una variable es entera no podemos cargarle una letra o un numero decimal.

Algunos ejemplos:

```
printf("Ingrese numero entero. n" ) ;
scanf("%d", &numero);

printf("Ingrese numero decimal. n" ) ;
scanf("%f", &numero_decimal ) ;


printf("Ingrese numero decimal. n" ) ;
scanf("%f", &numero_real ) ;

printf("Ingrese una letra. n" ) ;
scanf("%c", &letra) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto no tiene que ver mucho con el lenguaje, sino, con la función estándar que trae por defecto C.
La subrutina scanf necesita saber el tipo de dato de la variable porqué de eso depende que se logre hacer una conversión de datos de forma correcta.
Por ejemplo, esta es una implementación muy básica de scanf:

```
void scanf_(const char* format, void* p)
{
    char ch;
    switch(format[1])
    {
        case 's': //Si se lee un "string"
            while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
            {
                *(char*)p = ch;
                p = (char*)p + 1;
            }
            *(char*)p = '\0';
            break;
        case 'c': //Si se lee un caracter
            *(char*) p = getchar();
            break;
        case 'd': //Si se lee un entero
            *(int*)p = 0;
            while((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
                *(int*)p = (*(int*)p * 10) + (ch - '0');
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Si te das cuenta, esta función implícitamente usa punteros genéricos y para poder usarlos, se necesita hacer una conversión explícita (casting), por esta razón, es necesario especificar el formato (%d, %c, %s, %c, entre otros).
Por ejemplo, si ingreso por teclado 123, la función necesita convertir el "123" (que por defecto está en string) en "integer" y para eso, es obligatorio poner el especificador de formato, de lo contrario, sería imposible que scanf logre efectuar la conversión.